# React Firebase - Fetching an item by id

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Im trying to implement a details page for a set of projects. On the projects page i have an array filled with projects and showing in a listview. When i clik on a project it goes through to the details page with the :key in the url.

I have the object `this.props.params.key` which is the identifier for the project but how do i query firebase for that objects details and save it in an array?

Url would be something like

```
https://website.firebaseio.com/projects/uyrkbqetyqknnu
```

I basically want to send a GET request to that and grab the details.

Thanks

I have a collection of Items on Firebase

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuJem.png

All i really want to do is grab the values and fill some textfields with them.

something like `var subject = firebaseobject.item.subject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reference to the specific project data like this

```
var allProjectsRef = new Firebase('https://website.firebaseio.com/projects');
var projectRef = allProjectsRef.child('PROJECT-ID-GOES-HERE');
```

I'm guessing you want this to work for more than one project. You can pass `this.props.params.key` in as a variable like this:

```
var projectId = this.props.params.key;   
var allProjectsRef = new Firebase('https://website.firebaseio.com/projects');
var projectRef = allProjectsRef.child(projectId);
```

I'm not sure if this was intentional or just happened to be how you wrote the question, but most of the unique ids in firebase start with a hyphen, so if it's not returning anything, it might be because of that.

The complete documentation is available here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/child.html

Comment: I thought the projetcRef would be a straightforward array but its coming up with lots of data which im not sure of. Looks like lots of Meta Data. How would i for example use project.item?

Comment: Can you give us more information? Maybe an example of the object firebase returns and what you would like instead? 

Arrays in firebase can be a little tricky to understand at first. Firebase has to do some work to convert arrays to objects and back again in order to allow many users to edit the same data. I'm not sure, based on your question, where the issue lies.

Here is more info on arrays from firebase that might help: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html